# Edge "Pin to start"-Tile: Custom icon from web-application

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to set a custom icon on the "Pin to start"-Tile (Microsoft Edge: Open website -> Click on "Pin to start") from a web-application (some metadata-tag for instance)? I only get the default Edge icon for the tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
<meta name='msapplication-square70x70logo' content='./img/small.png' />
<meta name='msapplication-square150x150logo' content='./img/normal.png' />
<meta name='msapplication-wide310x150logo' content='./img/wide.png' />
<meta name='msapplication-square310x310logo' content='./img/large.png' />
```

also

```
<meta name='msapplication-TileColor' content='#1e90ff' />
```

for the colour on windows phone